# Pandas read_csv(): keep 0 as 0 (not convert it to NaN)

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am trying to read a csv file, of which a sample:

```
datetime,check,lat,lon,co_alpha,atn,status,bc
2012-10-27 15:00:59,2,0,0,2.427,,,
2012-10-27 15:01:00,2,0,0,2.407,,,
2012-10-27 15:02:49,2,0,0,2.207,-17.358,0,-16162
2012-10-27 15:02:50,2,0,0,2.207,-17.354,0,8192
2012-10-27 15:02:51,1,0,0,2.207,-17.358,0,-8152
2012-10-27 15:02:52,1,0,0,2.207,-17.358,0,648
2012-10-27 15:06:03,0,51.195076,4.444407,2.349,-17.289,0,4909
2012-10-27 15:06:04,0,51.195182,4.44427,2.344,-17.289,0,587
2012-12-05 09:21:34,,,,,42.960,1,16430
2012-12-05 09:21:35,,,,,42.962,1,3597
```

The problem I encounter is that in columns with only ints, the 0's are converted to NaN (eg columns 'check' and 'status', these are columns with only ints, but the column is read as floats because there are real missing values). But I only want the empty values to be converted to NaN, and not the zeros.

This is what I get:

```
>>> pd.read_clipboard(sep=',', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
                     check        lat       lon  co_alpha     atn  status     bc
datetime                                                                        
2012-10-27 15:00:59      2   0.000000  0.000000     2.427     NaN     NaN    NaN
2012-10-27 15:01:00      2   0.000000  0.000000     2.407     NaN     NaN    NaN
2012-10-27 15:02:49      2   0.000000  0.000000     2.207 -17.358     NaN -16162
2012-10-27 15:02:50      2   0.000000  0.000000     2.207 -17.354     NaN   8192
2012-10-27 15:02:51      1   0.000000  0.000000     2.207 -17.358     NaN  -8152
2012-10-27 15:02:52      1   0.000000  0.000000     2.207 -17.358     NaN    648
2012-10-27 15:06:03    NaN  51.195076  4.444407     2.349 -17.289     NaN   4909
2012-10-27 15:06:04    NaN  51.195182  4.444270     2.344 -17.289     NaN    587
2012-12-05 09:21:34    NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN  42.960       1  16430
2012-12-05 09:21:35    NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN  42.962       1   3597
```

So, in the columns 'check' and 'status', there are to many NaN's. In the 'lat' and 'lon' columns the 0's are not converted to NaN's.

- Using `na_values=''` and `keep_default_na=False` does not help. Is there a way to specify to not convert int 0's to NaN? Or is this a bug?
- I could specify the dtype of the specific columns as int with the `dtype` keyword. This keeps the 0's as 0's, but the problem is that those columns also contain real NaN's (empty values). So, in this case, these values are also converted to 0's as in an int column you cannot have NaN's. For this reason, I have to keep all columns as floats.

---

EDIT: after upgrading to pandas 0.10.1, it works as expected even without specifying `keep_default_na` and `na_values`:

```
>>> pd.read_clipboard(sep=',', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
                     check        lat       lon  co_alpha     atn  status     bc
datetime                                                                        
2012-10-27 15:00:59      2   0.000000  0.000000     2.427     NaN     NaN    NaN
2012-10-27 15:01:00      2   0.000000  0.000000     2.407     NaN     NaN    NaN
2012-10-27 15:02:49      2   0.000000  0.000000     2.207 -17.358       0 -16162
2012-10-27 15:02:50      2   0.000000  0.000000     2.207 -17.354       0   8192
2012-10-27 15:02:51      1   0.000000  0.000000     2.207 -17.358       0  -8152
2012-10-27 15:02:52      1   0.000000  0.000000     2.207 -17.358       0    648
2012-10-27 15:06:03      0  51.195076  4.444407     2.349 -17.289       0   4909
2012-10-27 15:06:04      0  51.195182  4.444270     2.344 -17.289       0    587
2012-12-05 09:21:34    NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN  42.960       1  16430
2012-12-05 09:21:35    NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN  42.962       1   3597
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get pandas.read\_csv to read empty values as empty string instead of nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867028/get-pandas-read-csv-to-read-empty-values-as-empty-string-instead-of-nan)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to first set `keep_default_na` to `False`:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',', index_col=0, keep_default_na=False, na_values='')

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
                     check        lat       lon  co_alpha     atn  status     bc
datetime                                                                        
2012-10-27 15:00:59      2   0.000000  0.000000     2.427     NaN     NaN    NaN
2012-10-27 15:01:00      2   0.000000  0.000000     2.407     NaN     NaN    NaN
2012-10-27 15:02:49      2   0.000000  0.000000     2.207 -17.358       0 -16162
2012-10-27 15:02:50      2   0.000000  0.000000     2.207 -17.354       0   8192
2012-10-27 15:02:51      1   0.000000  0.000000     2.207 -17.358       0  -8152
2012-10-27 15:02:52      1   0.000000  0.000000     2.207 -17.358       0    648
2012-10-27 15:06:03      0  51.195076  4.444407     2.349 -17.289       0   4909
2012-10-27 15:06:04      0  51.195182  4.444270     2.344 -17.289       0    587
2012-12-05 09:21:34    NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN  42.960       1  16430
2012-12-05 09:21:35    NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN  42.962       1   3597
```

From the doc-string of [`read_tables`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_table.html):

> `keep_default_na` : bool, default True
>        If `na_values` are specified and `keep_default_na` is `False` the default `NaN`
>       values are overridden, otherwise they're appended to
>
> `na_values` : list-like or dict, default `None`
>       **Additional** strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific
>       per-column NA values

Comment: It does not seem to make a difference with me (pandas 0.10.0), I still get NaN's instead of zeros.

Comment: @joris That's strange, perhaps upgrade to 0.10.1 ?

Comment: I added my output to my question. But I will try it with 0.10.1.

Comment: It's working in pandas 0.10.1! Thanks for the suggestion! But it even works without specifying `keep_default_na` and `na_values`.

Comment: @joris I think I'm going mad, I'm sure I tested that! You're quite correct.