# How to force pandas read_csv to distinguish betwen nan and empty string

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I would like pandas read_csv to properly read the following example text into a DataFrame:

`"INDEX"|"COLUMN_STRING"|"COLUMN_INTEGER"|"COLUMN_EMPTY"|"COLUMN_EMPTY_STRING"
1|"string"|21||""`

The file I need to parse has all the values that should be strings wraped with `""`.
Values that should be `NaN` are without double quotes, like that: `||`

I would like read_csv to keep all the "quoted" values as strings, also `""`, but
it forces `NaN` as a default value for `""`.

If I use `keep_default_na=False`, it sets empty strings `''` to both `||` and `|""|`.

Also, using `dtype={"COLUMN_EMPTY_STRING": str}` doesn't help.
Does anybody know the solution to this pickle?

Another possible solution, would be to use `quoting=3`. This would keep strings as `"string"`, which could be solved after parsing. I cannot use it though, since I'm providing `index_col` argument, which raises error since it cannot find e.g. `INDEX`, because it reads `"INDEX"` from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the file, one solution can be to pre-process the file in memory to replace all the occurrences of `||` with `|NaN|` using python `io.StringIO`

```
import io
from pandas.io.parsers import read_csv

with open( 'test.csv', 'r' )  as fin:
    with io.StringIO( fin.read( ).replace( '||', '|NaN|' )) as ios:
        df = read_csv( ios, na_values='NaN', sep='|',
                       index_col=["INDEX"], keep_default_na=False )
```

this is how `df` looks like:

```
      COLUMN_STRING  COLUMN_INTEGER  COLUMN_EMPTY COLUMN_EMPTY_STRING
INDEX                                                                
1            string              21           NaN
```

to verify:

```
print ( 'empty: >{}<, empty string: >{}<'.format( df.COLUMN_EMPTY[ 1 ], 
                                                  df.COLUMN_EMPTY_STRING[ 1 ] ))
empty: >nan<, empty string: ><
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it assigns type int64 to a value like that `|"12"|`. I would like it to keep it as a string. But I agree on the part where you change `||` to `|NaN|`, although would like to find a solution without additional string converting.

Comment: @user3055017 i think if all the values in a column are quoted numbers, the column is converted to a number type; you may either specify `dtype={"COLUMN_STRING": str}` as one of the arguments, or do `df.COLUMN_STRING = df.COLUMN_STRING.astype( str )` after reading the data

Answer (score 0):

There are three separate things going on in this question:

1. [Separation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) of columns using the pipe symbol, parameter: `pandas.read_csv( sep='|' )`
2. [Quote character](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) being used is double quotes, parameter: `pandas.read_csv( quotechar='"' )`
3. [Data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867028/get-pandas-read-csv-to-read-empty-values-as-empty-string-instead-of-nan/75622501#75622501) for columns needs to be string or number, parameter: `dtype={"COLUMN_EMPTY_STRING": 'string'}`  will force all values to primitive string including empty values