# pandas read_csv getting NaN values, using Python 3

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I am reading a CSV file saved from an MS SQL query. When I read file using pandas, the last column has long string which is causing NaN values. I understand this could be from windows end of line returns and/or encoding issues.

I am a newbie and don't really understand if this is an encoding problem and how to change the read statement.  When I use standard Python `import csv` and save as utf-8 I don't have any issues re-opening and working with a txt file. Also don't find anything particularly helpful from [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3501)

```
Location = r'newpositive.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(Location)
```

Comment: I'd need to see a sample from the file.

Comment: thanks ..here is link to file in shared google doc.https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7DcM13NyHAoRkE4eXNZV0M5Wk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The file I was using had carriage returns within columns and eol not properly defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get pandas.read\_csv to read empty values as empty string instead of nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867028/get-pandas-read-csv-to-read-empty-values-as-empty-string-instead-of-nan)