# Pandas: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I get **ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer** for following:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('zoom11.csv')
df[['x']] = df[['x']].astype(int)
```

- The "x" is a column in the csv file, I cannot spot any *float NaN* in the file, and I don't understand the error or why I am getting it.
- When I read the column as String, then it has values like -1,0,1,...2000, all look very nice int numbers to me.
- When I read the column as float, then this can be loaded. Then it shows values as -1.0,0.0 etc, still there are no any NaN-s
- I tried with *error_bad_lines = False* and dtype parameter in read_csv to no avail. It just cancels loading with same exception.
- The file is not small (10+ M rows), so cannot inspect it manually, when I extract a small header part, then there is no error, but it happens with full file. So it is something in the file, but cannot detect what.
- Logically the csv should not have missing values, but even if there is some garbage then I would be ok to skip the rows. Or at least identify them, but I do not see way to scan through file and report conversion errors.

Update: Using the hints in comments/answers I got my data clean with this:

```
# x contained NaN
df = df[~df['x'].isnull()]

# Y contained some other garbage, so null check was not enough
df = df[df['y'].str.isnumeric()]

# final conversion now worked
df[['x']] = df[['x']].astype(int)
df[['y']] = df[['y']].astype(int)
```

Comment: Try check it by `df[df['x'].isnull()]`

Comment: You need to figure out what you want to do with any NaNs, and then do it.

Comment: thanks @jezrael , now df[df['x'].isnull()] did identify a row with "NaN" and I could remove it ! Now with another similar field - this seems to have some other garbage which is not int. Is there generic way to find rows which are not convertable to given datatype, so I can identify and garbage them all?

Comment: Use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors = coerce` instead of astype int then `fillna` with whatever you want.

Comment: In v0.24, pandas introduces Nullable Integer Types which support Integer columns with NaNs. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55704512/4909087) for more information.

Comment: I came to this post because of getting same error, but in my case when I reset dataframe as df = df.reset_index(drop=True), it is resolved... Just commenting here if someone with mine like issue read this..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get pandas.read\_csv to read empty values as empty string instead of nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867028/get-pandas-read-csv-to-read-empty-values-as-empty-string-instead-of-nan)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

For identifying `NaN` values use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print(df[df['x'].isnull()])
```

Then for removing all non-numeric values use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` - to replace non-numeric values to `NaN`s:

```
df['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df['x'], errors='coerce')
```

And for remove all rows with `NaN`s in column `x` use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['x'])
```

Last convert values to `int`s:

```
df['x'] = df['x'].astype(int)
```

Comment: thanks, this was ok. I updated my question with my lines. Final thing what I do not understand is that why I get False for negative numbers: `'-1'.isnumeric()` ? Not issue for my data which had x and y >=0, but general question still, as I do not see it in official document.

Comment: you're probably seeing that because python is iterpreting `'-1'` as a string, which is not a number

Comment: I was having a `df.max()` on an empty `df`, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 42):

> ## ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

From v0.24, you actually can. Pandas introduces [Nullable Integer Data Types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#nullable-integer-data-type) which allows integers to coexist with NaNs.

Given a series of whole float numbers with missing data,

```
s = pd.Series([1.0, 2.0, np.nan, 4.0])
s

0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
3    4.0
dtype: float64

s.dtype
# dtype('float64')
```

You can convert it to a nullable int type (choose from one of `Int16`, `Int32`, or `Int64`) with,

```
s2 = s.astype('Int32') # note the 'I' is uppercase
s2

0      1
1      2
2    NaN
3      4
dtype: Int32

s2.dtype
# Int32Dtype()
```

Your column needs to have whole numbers for the cast to happen. Anything else will raise a TypeError:

```
s = pd.Series([1.1, 2.0, np.nan, 4.0])

s.astype('Int32')
# TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int32
```

Comment: I get an error saying `TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype` do you have any idea what this means?

Comment: Thanks for calling out "note the 'I' is uppercase".  That was my problem.

Comment: @Ken, I solved this using `s.astype(float).astype('Int32')`

Answer (score 30):

Also, even at the lastest versions of pandas if the column is **object** type you would have to convert into float first, something like:

```
df['column_name'].astype(np.float).astype("Int32")
```

NB: You have to go through numpy float first and then to nullable Int32, for some reason.

The size of the int if it's 32 or 64 depends on your variable, be aware you may loose some precision if your numbers are to big for the format.

Comment: It is better to use df['column_name'].astype('float').astype('Int32')

Answer (score 9):

I know this has been answered but wanted to provide alternate solution for anyone in the future:

You can use `.loc` to subset the dataframe by only values that are `notnull()`, and then subset out the `'x'` column only. Take that same vector, and `apply(int)` to it.

**If column x is float:**

```
df.loc[df['x'].notnull(), 'x'] = df.loc[df['x'].notnull(), 'x'].apply(int)
```

Comment: the left part does what it should but in the df it stays formated as float. (Python 3.6, Pandas 0.22)

Answer (score -1):

if you have null value then in doing mathematical operation you will get this error to resolve it use `df[~df['x'].isnull()]df[['x']].astype(int)` if you want your dataset to be unchangeable.