# Got this Error ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dates in this format 12/29/2011 as a string I guess and I only need Year so I write this function to extract year only but I got
"**ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer**"
Seems like I have Nan's somewhere and only solution I can think of is to drop the rows with Nan's but I cant do that coz I need the data from other columns.

```
 def get_year(date):
    year = ''
    try:
        year = date[-4:]
    except TypeError:
        year = str(date)[0:4]
    return (year).astype(int)
```

The get_year function works when I use this code

```
for i in df.index:
    if (not pd.isna(df['yearOpened'][i]) and get_year(df['yearOpened'][i]) > 1955):
            print('something')
```

I am using .loc and wants to know how to skip Nan's using .loc

```
`df.loc[get_year(df['yearOpened'])]`
```

Comment: There is no date. You can't make a correct date just appear. What value is passed to `get_year` when throwing this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333227/pandas-valueerror-cannot-convert-float-nan-to-integer?rq=1

Comment: @ifly6 values from column 'yearOpened' that are in these format as a string 12/12/1999

Comment: `ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-194-92a26aa153b4> in <module>
----> 1 df.loc[get_year(df['yearOpened'])]

<ipython-input-190-271b55d3efdf> in get_year(date)
      7         year = str(date)[0:4]
      8 #         print(year[0:4])
----> 9     return (year).astype(int)`

Comment: Just parse them with `pd.to_datetime(your_string_series)` and then access date with `date_series.dt.year`

Comment: @ifly6 will that handle the Nan error that is my main concern if the datasets doesnot have Nan or empty value my function works

Comment: `for i in df.index:
    if (not pd.isna(df['yearOpened'][i]) and get_year(df['yearOpened'][i]) > 1955):
            print('something')`
This works because not pd.isna handles the Nan values

Comment: `# df['year'] = df['yearBuilt'].str[0:2]
# df['year'] = df['year'].astype('Int32')
# df.head()`
Also Tried this but Nan values or missing values is the main concern

Comment: What is the value passed to `get_year` when this error is thrown?

Comment: **Please share the entire error message as well as a [mcve].**

Comment: The loop code you shared is quite unidiomatic, be careful. I would strongly recommend reading the Pandas docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's inbuilt datetime library to grab the year from your string with ease.

```
from datetime import datetime

date = '12/29/2011'
dt = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y') #create datetime object
dt.year

Output: 2011
```

OR

You could use the pandas.to_datetime function which will handle the nan values for you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = ['12/29/2011', '12/30/2012', np.nan]
dt = pd.to_datetime(dates)
dt.year

Output: Float64Index([2011.0, 2012.0, nan], dtype='float64')
```

**Edit (in response to comments)**

To get a DataFrame of all the bad rows you can simply index out all the rows that return `NaT` from the `pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], errors='coerce')` operation.

```
data = {'dates': ['12/29/2011', '12/30/2012', np.nan, '1/1/9999'],
        'values': [1,2,3,4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dt = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], errors='coerce')

bad_rows = df[dt.isna()] #indexing out all rows which contain nan values
bad_rows.to_csv('bad_data.csv')
```

Comment: Thank You this worked but got another error apparently data I am working with is not super clean
`OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00`

Comment: got Out of bound error with this :
`def get_year(date):
    pd.to_datetime(date)
    return dt.year
df.loc[get_year(df['yearBuilt'])]` 

Can anyone please suggest me how to handle error on this one  
OR 

 `def get_year(date):
    year = ''
    try:
        year = date[-4:]
    except TypeError:
        year = str(date)[0:4]
    return (year).astype(int)`

Ways to handle Nan on this one 
THANKS A LOT in advance

Comment: you could set errors to 'coerce': `dt = pd.to_datetime(dates, errors='coerce')`. This would replace the out of bound datetime with NaT. Not sure if this is what you want though.

Comment: I am trying to flag if the data has anything funky like that. So if the data has something like that or it's empty I need to save the whole row on different dataframe and export it to csv. Does that make sense ?

Comment: I have edited the answer with the solution to your problem as I understand it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @ ALS777 not exactly but that solved my problem. Thank you very much