# How to resolve "Pandas: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer" for a large dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to mask a pandas data frame and pass it to create a heatmap. I have used the following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('distance_matrix_Mult_Align.csv', index_col=0)
mask = np.zeros_like(df)
triangle_indices = np.triu_indices_from(mask)
mask[triangle_indices] = True
sns.heatmap(df, cmap="RdBu", center=0, vmin=-1, vmax=1, mask=mask)
```

I get an error message saying `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to intege`.
To check for any NaN values, I run the following code

```
check_for_NaN = df.isnull().values.any()
print(check_for_NaN)
```

The output was `False`. I found a post similar to mine ([Pandas: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333227/pandas-valueerror-cannot-convert-float-nan-to-integer)) but the dimensions of my dataframe is 640 × 640. So column-wise treatment seems impractical.

I am struggling to figure out the issue. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Add a small sample from  the actual data. Do `df[:2].to_dict()` and the output to the question.

Comment: What is the output of df.isna().values.any()

Comment: @ThePyGuy, I got another error ``ValueError: Must pass 2-d input``

Comment: @anarchy, ``False``

Comment: can u show me df.head()

Comment: @anarchy, sure! I get a 5 × 640 dataframe in the output. Should I give you the .csv file?

Comment: sure if you can put a link to the file, if you can give me the whole csv file that would be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Your commands work for me. Can you try updating your numpy and pandas ?

Comment: Thank you so much! I have uninstalled anaconda and then installed it again (I tried to update it multiple times with command like ``conda update conda``  ``conda install anaconda=versionNumber`` ``conda update --all`` etc. But none of these worked. How do you usually update anaconda?). Finally it's working :-)