# read_csv() shows only NaN

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
data = pd.open_csv('file.csv')
print(data)
```

gives this result:

```
    ��B  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3
0    NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1    NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2    NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
3    NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
4    NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
....
```

Why is this happening? Why is everything `NaN`?

Comment: What is the content in `file.csv`?

Comment: try also with read_csv()

Comment: The content is my bank transactions: date, name, sum and currency

Comment: Since the problem is one of file import, the data file is part of what we need to [reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). Please provide some data that causes the undesirable behavior (mock up that data if you cannot share the actual file or if it is too long), not a human summary of what is inside.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get pandas.read\_csv to read empty values as empty string instead of nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867028/get-pandas-read-csv-to-read-empty-values-as-empty-string-instead-of-nan)

Answer (score 0):

Common fixes would be either you have to mention your delimiter

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep = "\t")
```

or you have to check the text encoding type of your file. If it is not UTF type then encode it to a UTF type, save and try opening then.

Comment: it is UTF. sep='\t' leaves me with just one column of NaN values.

Comment: Please post a snap of your file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's an encoding issue? Are you sure the files has been encoded in the standard `utf-8`.

In any case, try to read your csv using:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header = 0, engine = 'python')
```

Hope this helps :)