# How to read NULL and blank in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The data I have is :

```
col1   col2      col3
 a             null value
```

When I load it into a pandas dataframe with `pd.read_csv`, I get:

```
 col1   col2    col3
  a      NaN    NaN
```

I don't want the blank space to be read as NULL,

so I have added `pd.read_csv('',na_filter=False)` ,

but with this the NULL value is also getting skipped, and I get:

```
col1   col2    col3
 a
```

The desired output is:

```
col1   col2    col3
 a              NaN
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68377524/2901002) solution