# How to read an excel file with data and some empty cells in panda's python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with huge dataset. I tried to read the excel file using the below command using pandas.

```
df = pd.read_csv(f'{cwd}/data.csv', keep_default_na=False, header=None)
print(df)
```

However the empty rows found in the csv file is missing in the output. I get something like below.

```
Input:       Output from the code:
    1               1
    2               2
    3               3
                    4
    4               5         
    5               6               
    6
```

Comment: `keep_default_na=False` might help. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43832955/2681662

Comment: I tried . It didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the parameter `skip_blank_lines=False` from `pandas.read_csv`. Here's a fixed version of your code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(f'{cwd}/data.csv', header=None, na_filter=False, skip_blank_lines=False)
df
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

**Or:**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(f'{cwd}/data.csv', header=None, skip_blank_lines=False)
df
```

**Outputs:**

[image]